# Reverse SSH Tunnel from windows to ubuntu to serve SQL server

Tags: ubuntu, windows, ssh, sql-server

just as the question says, I am currently trying to establish a reversed SSH connection from a Windows server behind a NAT to a hosted Ubuntu VPS. I'm pretty much a total beginner in Linux and SSH.

I'm running a PLink connection from the Windows machine with the following command:

```
plink.exe -ssh -R 3005:localhost:1433 deploy@test.website -pw password
```

On the VPS, I have added the following lines to sshd_config:

```
Match User deploy  
GatewayPorts yes
```

and restarted SSH. Netstat -an | grep 3005 brings back the following response:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3005            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3005          127.0.0.1:47578         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::3005                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:47578         127.0.0.1:3005          ESTABLISHED
```

To me, this looks right, but that's purely from me trying to decipher the info given. But my ruby webapp (Running on Padrino, Mizuno, and Nginx) refuses to connect to the SQL server on this port on localhost. Am I missing something?

Hope this is enough info to go on. If there's anything else, I'll try to supply it.

Comment: Do I get it right that the Windows machine is running SQL-Server on port 1433 and that the Linux machine is running the ruby webapp that is willing to connect to the DB through port 3005?

Comment: Could you also provide error message or log output from your ruby application?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, the SQL Server is port 1433 and the DB connection on the Ubuntu machine is 3005. I'll have a look here now about trying to get the ruby error output to stick up here. I have vague memories of a `connection closed` in the meantime.

Comment: `^[[31m  ERROR^[[0m - ^[[33m15/Jan/2014 15:26:15^[[0m DBI::DatabaseError - java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.:
 /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.8/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/dbd-jdbc-0.1.6-java/lib/dbd/jdbc/database.rb:59:in `prepare'
 /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.8/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/base_classes/database.rb:94:in `execute'
 /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.8/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles/database.rb:81:in `execute'`

The error I'm receiving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information you give (mainly the output of `netstat`), it looks like your port forwarding is ok.

You can have assurance on that by trying to open a connection to this port from the Ubuntu machine.  Try something like:

```
telnet localhost 3005
```

You should then fall in one of those 3 cases:

1. You get a message saying `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused` it means the port forwarding is not working, the port 3005 is still closed on the Ubuntu server.
2. You get messages with `connect_to localhost port 1433: failed.` and `Connected to localhost.` but directly closing with `Connection closed by foreign host.` it means that port forwarding is ok (first connect) but the listening port on your SQL server is not accepting the connection (second connect, even though the error message comes first).
3. You get an invite coming from the SQL Server and maybe then the connection will close.  If this is the case, it means port forwarding is working fine.  But the issue lies with your SQL server or the way your application if connecting to it.

I think you should be in 2. or 3.

Comment: Just gave this a try, and yes, I can indeed get a telnet connection. Ah well, at least this has written this off as a problem. I'll have a look at the other components.

Thanks for the pointers about where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

reverse tunnel? do you mean remote port forwarding? I think you are trying to forward a local port (where SQL server is running) to your remote Ubuntu server. if so then you need to do a local port forward instead (-L instead of -R)

Comment: My understanding must be backwards. I thought -R pushed the local port 1433 to be visible on the Ubuntu machine as localhost:3000, and -L tied the port 1433 on the Ubuntu machine to be reachable on the Windows machine at 3005. I'll give this a try and let you know how it works.

Comment: That's the other way round

Comment: When I run the command with -L, then I can't see port 3005 on the Ubuntu machine at all. It is only visible when I use -R, which seems like the correct behaviour. Sorry, I'm not trying to be stubborn in this. It's the Ubuntu machine trying to access the SQL server instance on the Windows machine, and the SSH connection is being created from the Windows to the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: I re-read the manpage and you're indeed right. You need a remote port forwarding. I find the term "port forwarding" a bit missleading as ssh actually forward connections instead of ports.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because the client is behind a NAT router.
If there were no NAT you could use:

`plink -ssh -R 3005:client-ip-addr:1433 deploy@ubuntu-ip-addr -pw passwd`

unfortunately the ubuntu server is unable to reach client-ip-addr. Maybe an Port forwarding to the sql server host:port could help but I guess that's exactly the kind of things you want to avoid.